# Tomcat 7 coontext path and war file name

Tags: tomcat, containers, tomcat7

Is there any configuration in tomcat context.xml file  so that if I give non-empty context path in the url and my ROOT.war is browsed ?

For eg - 
Browse localhost:8080 gives access to webapps/ROOT directory

I want - Browse localhost:8080/xyz should give access to webapps/ROOT directory.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Its there in conf/server.xml. just change the docbase thats enough.
There should be a directory named webapps/root

```
<Context path="/xyz" docBase="root"  privileged="true" />
```

This entry should be added with in the

```
<Host>...(add it here).... </Host>
```

tag. The position is important.

Comment: It will work. you should add it within the <Host>.....(add it here)   </Host>.... tag. and restart your tomcat.

Comment: This will deploy your application TWICE.  Once for the context / and once for /xyz.  Since your application is deployed for / then it can control any path underneath it.  Have your app handle the mapping and not tomcat.